# Get labels in current view

Tags: ios7, automation

I have a need to get all labels in current view. is it possible? If yes, please advise how can i realize this?

For example, i need to collect all labels from startup screen, then from currently showing popup and etc.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the way to go----

```
NSMutableArray *labels = [NSMutableArray array];
for (UIView *v in someSuperview.subviews) {
if ([v isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]]) {
    [labels addObject:v];
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose if you want to collect label in an array, you can try this:

```
for (UIView *subview in self.view.subviews)
{
    if(subview isKindOfClass:[UILabel class])
    {
        [arrayOfLabels addObject:subview];
    }
}
```

If you want it to do by means of accessibilityLabel, here are the steps to get view from given accessibilityLabel. Method viewContainingAccessibilityElement:element is extension method to UIAccessibilityElement class.

```
UIAccessibilityElement *element = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] accessibilityElementWithLabel:label];
UIView *view = (UIView*)[UIAccessibilityElement viewContainingAccessibilityElement:element];
```

Let me know if it works

Comment: I need it in accessibilityLabel way, could you please help me?